# How to sum columns to create a third one on specific rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
A B C V
1 4 7 T
2 6 8 T
3 9 9 F
```

and I want to create a new column, summing the rows where V is 'T'

So I want

```
A B C V D
1 4 7 T 12
2 6 8 T 16
3 9 9 F
```

Is there any way to do this without iteration?

Answer (score 2):

Mask the values before summing:

```
df.select_dtypes(np.number).sum(axis=1).mask(df['V'] != 'T')    
# Or,
df.select_dtypes(np.number).mask(df['V'] != 'T').sum(axis=1, skipna=False) 

0    12.0
1    16.0
2     NaN
dtype: float64

df['D'] = df.select_dtypes(np.number).sum(axis=1).mask(df['V'] != 'T')                                                                      
df                                                                                                                                        
   A  B  C  V     D
0  1  4  7  T  12.0
1  2  6  8  T  16.0
2  3  9  9  F   NaN
```

If you actually wanted blanks, use

```
df.select_dtypes(np.number).sum(axis=1).mask(df['V'] != 'T', '')                                                                          
0    24
1    32
2      
dtype: object
```

Which returns an object column (not recommended).

---

Alternatively, using `np.where`:

```
np.where(df['V'] == 'T', df.select_dtypes(np.number).sum(axis=1), np.nan)                                                                 
# array([12., 16., nan])

df['D'] = np.where(
    df['V'] == 'T', df.select_dtypes(np.number).sum(axis=1), np.nan)
df                                                                                                                                        
   A  B  C  V     D
0  1  4  7  T  12.0
1  2  6  8  T  16.0
2  3  9  9  F   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Numpy where

```
import numpy as np
df['D'] = np.where(df['V'] == 'T', df.select_dtypes(np.number).sum(axis=1), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['D'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']][df['V'] == 'T'].sum(axis=1)


In [51]df:
Out[51]: 
   A  B  C  V      D
0  1  4  7  T 12.000
1  2  6  8  T 16.000
2  3  9  9  F    nan
```